# Parallax/background-attachment:fixed not working in some browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can you help me with my code guys, my parallax effect working fine on any browser except on mobile google chrome app.

```css
    #collage_container{
        height:100%;
        background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/500x250');
        background-size:cover;
        background-position:center;
        background-attachment:fixed;
        background-repeat:no-repeat
        }
```

```html
<div id="collage_container">
    <div class="logo"><img src="images/mypinoy_logo.png"></div>
    <div class="tagline"><img src="images/tagline.png" ></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Yes background attachment do not work in chrome mobile you need to use js if you want to do it.

Comment: Thanks @Ashishsah what's the code for it?

Comment: You could use background-attachment: initial on smaller screens, but it's just disable the parallax effect

Comment: What is your chrome version??

Comment: Did you try using of any existing plugins like http://materializecss.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using `background-attachment` that can be a reason. Reffer to this link for making a parllax this may helps you and even supportive in chrome android. You have to use js...reffer to this website : http://javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/parallaxscrolling/index.shtml

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.